# Tried to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 but it failed - possibility to set up the system?

Tags: 16.04

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 until yesterday and thought maybe it's time to upgrade to the new version;
I did that and the upgrade was installing, when somewhere close to the end it stopped working -after that Ubuntu couldn't be started anymore;

I tried to repair the broken packages and succeeded in the meaning I have now Ubuntu 16.04 and I can start the graphical interface and my data is still there...
However I get lots of error messages when using the console, mostly this one:

```
 dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von mailutils:
 mailutils hängt ab von default-mta | mail-transport-agent; aber:
 Paket default-mta ist nicht installiert.
 Paket postfix, das default-mta bereitstellt, ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
 Paket mail-transport-agent ist nicht installiert.
 Paket postfix, das mail-transport-agent bereitstellt, ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

 dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes mailutils (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
 Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da das Limit MaxReports bereits erreicht ist.
Trigger für libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) werden verarbeitet ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
octave
liboctave-dev
postfix
mailutils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Don't know the English error messages, sorry...

`translate.google.com` says:

`dpkg : dependency problems prevent configuration of mailutils :
     mailutils depends on default- mta | mail -transport-agent ; but:
       Package default- mta is not installed.  
     Postfix package , the default- mta provides is not configured yet.
     Package mail -transport-agent is not installed.  
     Package postfix which mail -transport-agent provides , is not configured yet .  
     dpkg : error processing the packet mailutils ( --configure ) :
       Dependency problems - remains unconfigured  
     There was no apport report written because the limit has already been reached MaxReports .
      Triggers for libc -bin ( 2.23-0ubuntu3 ) are processed ...
     Errors were encountered while processing: octave liboctave -dev postfix mailutils 
     E : Sub -process / usr / bin / dpkg returned on error code ( 1 )`

So I don't really now how to solve those error messages and thought maybe it's a better idea to set up Ubuntu totally new..

I can't find a USB-stick so is there a way over the console to reinstall Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry about the issue. There is the `xterminal`. Launch that and try fixing from there, if that doesn't work then in my own understanding and experience you will need to get a `USB stick` to do a complete re-install. As you can see `even the console tool` isn't functioning so you need that. Don't know if any other means exists. Try this `xterm &` in the current console to launch the `xterminal` then try your earlier fix.